Location Permission Pop-up Not Working in Headless Mode with Selenium
I'm currently working on a Selenium WebDriver automation script using Python, running on a window machine. My goal is to handle location permission pop-ups and allow location access in headless mode.
Problem Statement
In non-headless mode, my script works perfectly. However, when I switch to headless mode, the location permission alert is not being handled as expected. As a result, I'm unable to set the location, and my tests fail.
code :
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
import re


class SeleniumProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--headless")

        options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1200')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

        # Set preferences to allow location access
        prefs = {
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1, 
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.instamart_default_url = "https://www.swiggy.com/instamart"


    def parse_quantity(self, quantity_text):
        match = re.match(r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)", quantity_text)
        if match:
            
            return match.group(1), match.group(2)
        return quantity_text, "" 
    


    def set_delivery_location(self):
        try:
            print('---------setting the delivery location----------')
            print(f"Opening Instamart page: {self.instamart_default_url}")
            self.browser.get(self.instamart_default_url)
            time.sleep(5)  


            print("Clicking the delivery area")
            delivery_area = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="address-bar"]')
            delivery_area.click()
            time.sleep(2)  

            print("Clicking 'Enter location manually'")
            enter_location_manually = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sc-aXZVg frxCck _22O3r" and text()="Enter Location Manually"]')
            print(f"Element HTML: {enter_location_manually.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
            enter_location_manually.click()
            time.sleep(10)  


            print("Clicking 'use as my current location  '")
            use_current_location = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_3nINI"]')
            print(f"Element found: {use_current_location.text}")
            print(f"Element HTML: {use_current_location.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
            use_current_location.click()
            time.sleep(5)

            # Extract and print the location address
            address = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "sc-aXZVg fVWuLc _1-Bgd")]').text
            print(f"Location set to: {address}")

            print("after turn on  , comfirm  location click")
            confirm_location = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_2xPHa _2qogK" and text()="Confirm Location"]')
            confirm_location.click()
            time.sleep(5)
            

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred while setting delivery location: {e}")
    
    def search_product(self, search_query):
        try:
            print('---------searching and extracting products----------')
            print(f"Opening swiggy Instamart page: {self.instamart_default_url}")
            self.browser.get(self.instamart_default_url)
            time.sleep(5) 
            
            print("Clicking the search container")
            search_container = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-testid="search-container"]')
            search_container.click()
            time.sleep(2)  

            print("Entering search query")
            input_box = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="search"]')
            input_box.clear()
            input_box.send_keys(search_query)
            input_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            time.sleep(5)  
            
            print(f"Search completed for query: {search_query}")
            
        
            results = self.extract_search_results()
            if results:
                self.save_results_to_csv(search_query, results)

            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred during search: {e}")
    
    def extract_search_results(self):
        results = []
        try:
            container = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="children-wrapper"]')
            items = container.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="default_container_ux4"]')
            
            for index, item in enumerate(items):
                try:
                    name = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'novMV').text
                    brand = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'bOMOAM').get_attribute("aria-label") if item.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'bOMOAM') else "N/A"
                    quantity_element = item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="item-quantity"]/div').text
                    price = item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@data-testid="itemMRPPrice"]/div').get_attribute('aria-label')
                    is_advertisement = 'true' if item.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="badge-wrapper"]') else 'false'
                    quantity, unit = self.parse_quantity(quantity_element)
                    result = {
                        'Rank': index + 1,
                        'Brand': brand,
                        'Name': name,
                        'Quantity': quantity,
                        'Quantity Unit':unit,
                        'Price': price,
                        'isAdvertisement': is_advertisement
                    }
                    results.append(result)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error extracting data for item {index}: {e}")
            return results
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred during result extraction: {e}")
            return results


    def save_results_to_csv(self, search_query, results):
        try:
            sanitized_query = re.sub(r'\W+', '_', search_query).lower()
            output_path = os.path.join('output', 'search', f"{sanitized_query}.csv")
            df = pd.DataFrame(results)
            df.to_csv(output_path, index=False)
            print(f"Results saved to {output_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error saving results to CSV: {e}")





    # def _get_page_content(self, url):
    #     self.browser.get(url)
    #     html_content = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    #     return BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    


Observations:
In headless mode, the location permission pop-up is not handled, and the script fails to set the location.
Request for Help
How can I ensure that the location permission is correctly handled in headless mode? Are there any additional steps or configurations required to make this work? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

try with "--headless=new"
